# What is the correct way to get the logged user via spring security (angularjs)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

After success login, how I can retrieve the logged users in spring `RestController`?

I use the below method/principle to get the logged user, but it retrieves anonymousUser instead of logged user.

```
Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

or

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
```

Comment: Here what I get in my print console.
`org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@905571d8: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 0125899A0DC1CF4F5C5A5416E1D1E49C; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS`

Answer (score 1):

You may get the logged in user name from Authentication object. To get the user object, you can then use the username retrieved from the authentication object.

Something like this should work:

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName();
User user = userService.findByUserName(name);
```

Or better, you can use Principal in your controller as an argument, and let the Spring pass the correct principal object. If the user not logged in, it would be null.

```
 public String hello(Principal principal ) {

  String name = principal.getName();
  User user = userService.findByUserName(name);

}
```

Ps: If you are getting anonymous authentication, then the user is not authenticated. SecurityContext returns anonymous authentication is the user is not logged in.
`

Comment: `Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String name = auth.getName();`
retrieve the "`anonymousUser`" for that.

Comment: Check out the note I just added in the answer.